# Inputting data (from a spreadsheet) into a web form without an API

Tags: forms, excel, lotus-notes, bulkloader, bulk-load

This is most likely a very noob question. There is an office workflow I am trying to make more efficient. The basic situation is this: The company receives information from multiple entities many times a day in handwritten formats via fax or scan. Right now, the employees are reading the handwritten info and typing it into a web form and submitting that information -- lots of going back and forth and clicking. Each record goes in manually. Then they're retyping that information from the handwritten forms into other databases (some of which support bulk .csv inserting, some of which don't). I'm thinking if the employees could read and type the information **once** into an excel spreadsheet, then use that excel spreadsheet to load the information into the web form(s) and do a bulk upload when they can. The workflow changes depending on each situation, but there is gross inefficiency in the employee workflow and I am hoping that there is a programming solution for one or more of the steps in this process.

The main problem is the first web form. The site is old as hell -- it is a state government site -- and doesn't have an API (that the state knows of, I've contacted them). It's a .nsf site (and requires you to log in). I understand that .nsf is a Lotus Notes database. I don't have a rating of 10 yet, so I'm not able to post images directly here, but here's a link to the image: http://postimg.org/image/5ns2k844h/

Since the state agency doesn't have an API (and they don't seem to care that this process is incredibly cumbersome), is there a way build a program or is there a current program that can input this information quickly? Any help at all will be greatly appreciated!

BB

Comment: You can use VBA to automate IE and enter information into fields on a web page. Excactly how you do that depends on the exact page.  Lots of info out there if you Google (e.g.) "automate IE VBA".  Also plenty of questions here on SO addressing this need.

Comment: Thank you, Tim! I'll take a look and see what I can find. Literally didn't have a clue where to start/how to search so this helps quite a bit. I'll try to follow up to this post with any solutions I can dig up. Cheers. BB

Comment: use GreaseMonkey it's the easiest

Comment: Thanks Paul. I'll check it out too.